# WIndows Phone 7 , PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-7.1.1

I'm starting developing applications for windows phone 7 with the PhoneGap, but i cant know how to start ,any suggestion

Comment: down voter thanks for your feedback, but an answer would be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking the basics, You need to check http://phonegap.com/start#wp

Answer (score 1):

Below are some links for you to get started on PhoneGap on Windows Phone.

- [Windows Phone and PhoneGap Series – Article #1 to #10](http://www.ginktage.com/2012/02/windows-phone-and-phonegap-series-article-1-to-10/)
- [“Hello World “Windows Phone Application using PhoneGap or Cordova](http://debugmode.net/2012/05/08/hello-world-windows-phone-application-using-phonegap-or-cordova/)